# Firefox says certificate is untrusted even though the certificate chain is good

Tags: firefox, azure, ssl, https, openssl

HTTPS for https://www.bigfont.ca is working in Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Safari but not in Firefox. It also passes all the tests at [this SSL Checkers](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.bigfont.ca). Firefox says:

> An error occurred during a connection to www.bigfont.ca. 
>   Peer's certificate has been marked as not trusted by the user. 
>   (Error code: sec_error_untrusted_cert)

This is a known situation with Firefox. We looked at the [StartSSL FAQ](https://www.startssl.com/?app=25) and the advice is:

> You must add the intermediate CA certificate to your installation.

We are using SmartSSL and OpenSSL to create an SSL Certificate. So, we added the intermediate CA certificate by following [Troy Hunt's tutorial](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/09/the-complete-guide-to-loading-free-ssl.html) and ran this command to create the PFX.

```
OpenSSL> pkcs12 -export -in bigfont.ca.crt -inkey bigfont.ca-encrypted.key 
-certfile sub.class1.server.ca.pem -out bigfont.ca.pfx -password pass:my-password
```

We uploaded the resultant `bigfont.ca.pfx` file to at the Azure Website's Config page.

[image: Windows Azure Website Configuration]

To test further, we ran `openssl s_client -servername www.bigfont.ca -connect www.bigfont.ca:443 -showcerts`. The results show that the certificate chain is working well.

```
depth=1 C = IL, 
O = StartCom Ltd., 
OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, 
CN = StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA

verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0

---
Certificate chain

 0 s:
      /description=T8eg9X1a04Scp3hM
      /C=CA
      /CN=www.bigfont.ca
      /emailAddress=shaunluttin@bigfont.ca
   i:
      /C=IL
      /O=StartCom Ltd.
      /OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing
      /CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

 1 s:
      /C=IL
      /O=StartCom Ltd.
      /OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing
      /CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
   i:
      /C=IL
      /O=StartCom Ltd.
      /OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing
      /CN=StartCom Certification Authority

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=
      /description=T8eg9X1a04Scp3hM
      /C=CA
      /CN=www.bigfont.ca
      /emailAddress=shaunluttin@bigfont.ca
issuer=
      /C=IL
      /O=StartCom Ltd.
      /OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing
      /CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA

---
No client certificate CA names sent

---
SSL handshake has read 3369 bytes and written 547 bytes

---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: 6E1F00009...FDD7B7BF7B7
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 2FA3C020A506198C1319081F9E023D35...5AEB01985323AADCF9
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1413947020
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) 

---
read:errno=10054
```

If the chain is working, why does Firefox complain?

Comment: I've gone through a few days and several 2nd level technicians trying to get a similar problem solved on a LAMP stack using a GeoTrust cert. I seem to remember that we tried alternative Apache commands for specifying the Intermediate Cert, and we played around with putting a few keys together into a single .pem (??). Good luck. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

**[Reset Firefox to its default state](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems#w_reset-firefox-to-its-default-state)**.

1. Firefox
2. Help
3. Troubleshooting Information
4. Reset Firefox

### Details

The problem turned out to be related to the `cert8.db` file that stores the Firefox certificates. Find it here:

1. Firefox
2. Help
3. Troubleshooting Information
4. Application Basics
5. Profile Folder
6. Show Folder

The problem was *probably* that we messed with Firefox's *Authorities* Certificate for StartCom. We probably did this while muddling thru the process of restoring our StartSSL *Client Authentication* certificate.

### Your Certificates (Client Authentication)

[image]

### Authorities

We probably accidentally messed with these, thereby making Firefox not trust StartCom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't relevant when the question was asked, but it is worth mentioning now.

A lot of browsers has [stopped trusting StartCom](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html).

The previous answers might still help with similar problems for other issuers than StartCom.

But if you are still using StartCom, you might want to switch to https://letsencrypt.org

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the CA certificate and importing it again did the trick for me.